# Python - click library pass option in function?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

With click library, can you pass an option in a function so it doesn't have to be passed into the cli?

So for this instead of having to pass -s in the cli, can I pass it in the function?

```
@block.command()
@click.option('--prefix', '-p', help='Prefix', required=False)
@click.option('--suffix', '-s', help='Prefix', required=True)
def test(prefix=None, suffix=None):
    if prefix: 
        print('p')
    elif suffix: print('suffix')
```

Comment: I believe the option decorator accepts a default keyword argument

Comment: That's a good idea. Yep, this works.